# Increment for each list item

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to increment the `z-index` of each list item.

This is what I tried so far:

```
    var photos = $('ul');
  photos.each(function () {

      var photos = $(this).children();
      var photosLen = photos.length;
      if (photosLen > 1) {
          photos.parent().addClass('album');
          var i = 0;
          while (i < photosLen) {

              $(this).children().css({
                  'z-index': i
              });
          }
      }

  });
```

I expected each list-item would go from `z-index: 1;` to `z-index: 3;` But It's not doing that. Just adds the length of the array to each list-item.

HTML: (Code would only apply to the first un-ordered list)

```
<ul>

    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PuwwFs.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjAGks.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/zA4lCs.jpg" alt=""></li>

  </ul>
    <ul>

        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PuwwFs.jpg" alt=""></li>


    </ul>
```

Comment: Isn't `photos.parent()` the same as `$(this)`?

Comment: haha no it's not... I need to name my variables more carefully....

Comment: Really? You don't think that `$(this).children().parent()` is the same as `$(this)`? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery the code could be simply

```
  if (photosLen > 1) {
      photos.each(function(i) {
          $(this).css('zIndex', i);
      })
      .parent()
      .addClass('album');
  }
```

Note the `each()` and the camelCase syntax for `z-index` property

Answer (score 0):

You forget to increment the value of `i` in your code :

```
      while (i < photosLen) {

          $(this).children().css({
              'z-index': i
          });
          i++; 
      }
```